# Is the conclusion of this proposition correct?

Tags: propositional-calculus

1. $¬Q \lor (R \land S) $
2. $P \lor Q $
3. $P \land R \land S$

clause 1 and clause 2 can create clause 3?

Comment: Are you asking if (1 and 2) implies 3?

Answer (score 1):

$$(¬Q \lor (R \land S)) \land (P \lor Q)$$
$$\equiv ((¬Q \lor (R \land S)) \land P) \lor ((¬Q \lor (R \land S)) \land Q)$$
$$\equiv ((¬Q \lor (R \land S)) \land P) \lor ((\neg Q \land Q) \lor (Q \land R \land S)$$
$$\equiv ((¬Q \lor (R \land S)) \land P) \lor (F \lor (Q \land R \land S)$$
$$\equiv ((¬Q \lor (R \land S)) \land P) \lor (Q \land R \land S) $$
$$\equiv (P \land \neg Q) \lor (P \land R \land S)  \lor (Q \land R \land S) $$
Now,
$$P \land R \land S \implies  (P \land \neg Q) \lor (P \land R \land S)  \lor (Q \land R \land S) $$
i.e., $$P \land R \land S \implies (¬Q \lor (R \land S)) \land (P \lor Q)$$
which means clause 3 $\implies$(clause 1 $\land$ clause 2)

Comment: Here, $F$ is a fallacy (or contradiction). So, $F \lor p \equiv p$ for any statement $p$.